# Is there a way to fetch a class with associated classes in a single SELECT query in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entitygraph

I have two classes, **A** and **B** with a One-To-Many relationship.

```
@Entity
public class A {
   //some code
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "abc")
   private List<B> b;
}
```

I have a JPA Repository for **A**, and I observed that when I fetch an **A** from the database with a repository method, **B**s are not included. When I want to access **B**s, additional SELECT queries are executed to fetch associated **B**s(if there are 100 associated **B**s, 100 additional queries are executed). making FetchType.EAGER only changes *when* these additional SELECT queries are executed. i.e. they are called right after the main SELECT query. Either way, additional SELECT queries are executed to fetch associated classes.

Is this natural behavior? I found that [JPA Entity Graphs](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-named-entity-graphs) is the solution for this issue/to fetch **A** with **B**s with a single SELECT query. Are there any other ways to address this issue? The problem with `@EntityGraph` is it has to be annotated with each repository method separately. Also, is there a way to annotate `@EntityGraph` once so it affects all the methods in the Repository?

I'm using Spring Boot 2.5.1. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You must enable [batch transactions](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-batch-inserts) to make it work as expected

Comment: Please read https://thorben-janssen.com/5-ways-to-initialize-lazy-relations-and-when-to-use-them/